# How do i pull data from one worksheet to another where a column includes a specific date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, auto, populate

I am struggling with an Excel Spreadsheet and hopefully someone can help.

It has two worksheets, "Database" and "Printsheet"

In the database, there are several columns, A:A contains an unique number, B:B contains dates and C:C Contains names.

Printsheet has a cell to put a date in (A:2) and a table beneath.

The idea is that the table in the "Printsheet" will auto populate with all rows from "Database" that contain the date entered to be able to print off.

I have tried allsorts, there is no "Filter" formula available in my version of excel which a lot online seems to suggest.

So far i seem to be able to bring all values from database but they do not filter out the other dates.
Can anyone help please?

It is something like :-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!B:B,MATCH(A2),Database!$A:$A,0)),"")
```

for column A of the Table etc etc but it doesnt seem to work.
Any help appreciated

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX(Database!A$2:A$200,
  SMALL(IF(Database!B$2:B$200=A2,ROW(Database!A$2:A$200)-ROW(Database!A$2)+1),
  ROWS(Database!A$2:A2))),"")
```

This formula just brings up all unique numbers regardless of the date in column Database!B:B

Database

| # | Trip Date | Location | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 04/12/2023 | Chatsworth | Amanda M |
| 2 | 05/11/2023 | Newark | Amanda P |
| 3 | 04/12/2023 | Chatsworth | Andy C |
| 4 | 04/12/2023 | Chatsworth | Andy F |
| 5 | 04/12/2023 | Chatsworth | Andy F |
| 6 | 04/12/2023 | Chatsworth | Anita B. |

Printsheet

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/12/2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Chatsworth |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| # | Date | Name | Contact Telephone Number | P-up Location | Deposit | Paid In Full |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please post some sample data using **[Markdown-Table-Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** so we can reproduce your example.

Comment: I tried the markdown, it worked on the printsheet table of data but not the database

Comment: Perhaps you should look at how you complete the match: "IFERROR(INDEX(Database!B:B,MATCH(A2),Database!$A:$A,0)),"") ", I suggest: "IFERROR(INDEX(Database!B:B,MATCH(A2,Database!$A:$A,0)),"") " as it looks like you close the match() function too early.

Comment: Thankyou, i tried this formula it just brought back a blank cell

Comment: This formula should work for you, you need to lock the cell A2, `=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!A$2:A$200,
  SMALL(IF(Database!B$2:B$200=A$2,ROW(Database!A$2:A$200)-ROW(Database!A$2)+1),
  ROWS(Database!A$2:A2))),"")  `

Comment: If you have access to `Power Query` you can do it as well. It will be very neat and easy as well

Comment: For that reason I have posted a screenshot in the answers section you can see its working. Oh i forgot to mention one more edit your formula needed was : `=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!A$2:A$200,   SMALL(IF(Database!B$2:B$200=A$2,ROW(Database!A$2:A$200)-ROW(Database!A$2)+1),   ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")` the last `ROWS()` function should not be referring to Database sheet instead it should refer the sheet where it is entering the formula, hence it would be `Printsheet!A$2:A2` instead of `Database!A$2:A2`

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$7,
  AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$7)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($F$1=$B$2:$B$7),ROWS(F$3:F3)),
  MATCH(F$2,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"") This comment worked, thankyou so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, you could try using the <kbd>AGGREGATE( )</kbd> function as well, instead of <kbd>SMALL()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$7)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($F$1=$B$2:$B$7),ROW(A1)),{1,2,4}),"")
```

---

Change the ranges and references as per your suit.

---

Or, make it bit dynamic by adding a function called <kbd>MATCH()</kbd> for the column index, also change the date to trip date.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$7,
  AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$7)-ROW($B$2)+1)/($F$1=$B$2:$B$7),ROWS(F$3:F3)),
  MATCH(F$2,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

---

Fill down and fill across!

---